# Child Object Placement based on Parent Object Angle

Tags: andengine

I want to perform object placement based on parent object position.

For example, I have chest and head object. I want when I rotate chest object then as per chest rotation head object also rotate and transform.

For this thing to achieve I did following stuff but I don't achieve desire effect and can't able to understand what was I doing?

```
private void addRectangle(float angle) {

    Rectangle baseRectangle = new Rectangle(300f, 300f, 100f, 200f);
    baseRectangle.setRotationCenter(0f, 0f);
    baseRectangle.setRotation(angle);
    // red base rectangle
    baseRectangle.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f);
    mMainScene.attachChild(baseRectangle);

    float tAngle = MathUtils.atan2(-200, 100f);
    float dist = FloatMath.sqrt(50 * 50 + 50 * 50);

    float pX = baseRectangle.getX()
            + FloatMath.cos(MathUtils.degToRad(baseRectangle.getRotation())
                    + tAngle) * dist;
    float pY = baseRectangle.getY()
            + FloatMath.sin(MathUtils.degToRad(baseRectangle.getRotation())
                    + tAngle) * dist;

    Rectangle childRectangle = new Rectangle(pX, pY, 50f, 50f);
    childRectangle.setRotationCenter(0f, 0f);
    childRectangle.setRotation(angle);
    // green child rectangle
    childRectangle.setColor(0f, 1f, 0f);
    mMainScene.attachChild(childRectangle);

}
```

As function argument I provide desire angle on which both the object needs to be rotated.
Someone please help me to get out from this problem.

Comment: Here I want to know how object get placed based on other object angle and position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your angle and distance formula wrong.
in your child position you get angle and dist that i define below code.

```
private void addRectangle(float angle) {
    float centerX, centerY;
    Rectangle baseRectangle = new Rectangle(300f, 300f, 200, 100f);
    centerX = baseRectangle.getX() + baseRectangle.getWidth() / 2;
    centerY = baseRectangle.getY() + baseRectangle.getHeight() / 2;
    baseRectangle.setRotation(angle);
    baseRectangle.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f);
    mScene.attachChild(baseRectangle);
    float tAngle = -0.2f;
    float dist = 128f;
    float pX = centerX + FloatMath.cos(MathUtils.degToRad(angle) + tAngle)
            * dist;
    float pY = centerY + FloatMath.sin(MathUtils.degToRad(angle) + tAngle)
            * dist;
    Rectangle childRectangle = new Rectangle(pX, pY, 50f, 50f);
    childRectangle.setRotationCenter(0, 0);
    childRectangle.setRotation(angle);
    childRectangle.setColor(0f, 1f, 0f);
    mScene.attachChild(childRectangle);
}
```

Comment: This thing create another problem for me. In the above code you change the rotation center of child object so when I attach body to this object creates abnormal behavior. Because of different rotation point of child object and its body. So what to do in this situation?

Comment: if your child not movement after attaching parent and child then 
after attachChild change your rotation center of your child.
or give me some code to identify wht a pro ?

Comment: Basically I understand from your statement is that first I have to create object with corner rotation center at that time my object body was static and then change rotation center to its normal position when I need dynamic body. I tried this thing in same code only. I attach bodies in the above rectangles and get this problem. This thing I will check and reply you. Am I understand any wrong thing then please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: you can create body after attachChild or change rotation center.

Comment: Yes now it works perfect.

Comment: @Siddharth you are genius :-P

Comment: You write more than necessary. I created ragdoll that fires at particular angle. But I have another problem in that. If there are around 5 ragdoll in the screen then performance of game become poor because each fire I create new ragdoll. This thing happen in low processor device only otherwise it work well. But I want to improve this thing also so what next I have to do as per your suggesion? Also thanks for your guidance.